# Steam won't start on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: steam, ubuntu-gnome

I'm using latest Ubuntu GNOME. When I download the steam-installer though software it works, after that nothing happens no update and it won't launch.

Here is the error message I get when I try to launch steam in a terminal:

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu
16.04 64-bit STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically 
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1461972496)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: whats the error messages?
Did you run it through terminal? Post the output here.

Comment: using hybrid graphics system?

Comment: No error message, no terminal nothing.  Its AMD hybrid graphics chip7850k

Comment: Please open a terminal, then start steam from there by typing `steam` then copy and paste the output as an edit to your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked finally (in terminal type):

```
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1{,.disable}
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6{,.disable}
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3{,.disable}
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.12.1{,.disable}
```

Comment: If this step doesnt work for you, try the next steps posted below

Comment: try above commands 1 and 2, then type steam on terminal, if not try 3 and 4 and retry steam on terminal

Answer (score 1):

You need not download Steam installer as it is already present in official Ubuntu repository. Do the following:

1. Remove Steam, fix broken dependencies, update installed packages

```
sudo su
apt remove --purge steam
apt autoremove
apt -f install
apt update
apt upgrade
```

2.1 Option 1: Install Aptitude:

```
apt install aptitude
aptitude install steam
```

2.2 Option 2: install Synaptic:

```
apt install synaptic
synaptic
```

Synaptic pop up box appears. On search panel type steam. A number of apps appear in list. one of them is steam. click on the box immediate to it's left. It will ask for confirmation to install dependencies. Click yes. Click apply. After it has finished close the window.

3. If all fails remove `libstdc++`

```
cd ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/
rm \
  amd64/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_amd64 \
  amd64/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_amd64.md5 \
  amd64/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_amd64 \
  amd64/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_amd64.md5 \
  amd64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.a \
  amd64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.map \
  amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 \
  amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18 \
  amd64/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6 \
  amd64/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6-4.6-pic \
  i386/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_i386 \
  i386/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_i386.md5 \
  i386/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_i386 \
  i386/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_i386.md5 \
  i386/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.a \
  i386/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.map \
  i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 \
  i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18 \
  i386/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6 \
  i386/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6-4.6-pic \
  ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6
```

4. Remove `libgcc_s`

```
cd ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/
rm \
  amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 \
  i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

5. Also

```
 rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

6. Then repeat either of the above methods

Comment: Did everything, but synaptic marks only to uninstall steam no dependencies that I could see.

Comment: This error on synaptic(spanish):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          `ubuntu-drivers-common:i386:
 Depende: python3-apt pero no va a ser instalado
 Depende: python3-xkit  but it is not installable
  Entra en conflicto: ubuntu-drivers-common  pero se va a instalar 1:0.4.17.1`

Comment: did you do sudo apt remove --purge steam?

Comment: Yes, what can I do next? think is driver problem?

Comment: You can try apt install aptitude && aptitude -f install

Comment: When you do apt update do you get any broken package error? Try dpkg -- configure -a

Comment: after removing completely I get this:                                                           `pablo@pablo-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc`

Comment: No more lib problem, but still getting that error

Answer (score 1):

```
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete steam's own lib using:

```
find ~/.steam/root/ -name "libgpg-error.so*" -print -delete
```

Found solution here: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/48994

Comment: After this steam looks like this:                                                                     `pablo@pablo-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ steam update
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc`

Comment: still same error, everytime I download the .deb file from steam site terminal prompts "hit return to continue", I hit enter and the terminal closes and nothing happens.