# Steam/Counter-Strike on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, steam

I downloaded Steam on Ubuntu 16.04. I was getting a bunch of different errors and managed to fix them by deleting two files: `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s`.

This allowed Steam to open however not Counter Strike.

```
    $ steam
    Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
    STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
    /bin/bash: /home/squanchy/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
    grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
    grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
    grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
```

Now opening Steam works and opens the application however running it through the command line causes it to exit "running mode??". Not quite sure how to describe it, essentially I can now type in the command line and it stops showing what commands steam is running.

I've tried a bunch of other commands

```
steam steam://rungameid/730
```

```
LD_PRELOAD=’/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6′ DIAPLAY=:0 steam
```

EDIT: Clarification I hope.

Any help would be nice. Many thanks.

Comment: > How was Steam **installed**? > Could you provide **screenshots**? > Try **running** this from **commandline**..
>> **LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam**
>>> [**found it here - take a look**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761176/steam-doesnt-start-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04) I run on amd64 too. I'll see what happens when I install & launch CS. Which version? (CS:S,CS:GO)

Comment: Yea that did manage to both open steam and counterstrike, however the frame rate was appalling. We are talking about less than 1,  as a result I will be switching all of my gaming to the number one gaming platform, aka windows.  Thanks a lot none the less.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steam won't start on ubuntu GNOME 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/784141/steam-wont-start-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04)

Comment: Yea it probably is. I got the problem sorted however do you know how to delete this post?

Comment: <1 FPS is almost certainly caused by not having the video drivers installed. Just in case anyone wanders by. I play CS:GO a lot via Steam on Kubuntu with an AMD Kaveri chip: `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` takes me from 1FPS to enough to play well.

Answer (score 1):

First backup your CS:GO data (and others games) in order to saving your time to download it back. Your CS:Go should be in `~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike\ Global\ Offensive` directory.

```
mv ~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike\ Global\ Offensive ~/
```

remove your current Steam, and install it back by:

> sudo apt-get install steam

it should install all dependencies libs. remove the `.steam` directory in your home before run the app and than mv back the backup files to where it belongs